# Help understanding a heating iron circuit component

Tags: soldering

I am trying to understand a soldering iron PCB circuit.
I am trying to use a different range circuit for my prototype.

Can someone please elaborate how it is controlling the temperature?

Secondly, I am unable to get any details of D8 (blue component near LED) as C32 written on it.

[image: PCB TOP Side Image]
[image: PCB Bottom Side Image]
[image: Hand Drawn Circuit]

Comment: Start by tracing out the circuit and drawing the schematic. You may have to do this three times or more to get it into a sensible layout. If you mirror the image of the underside of the board it will be easier. There is a schematic drawing tool on the editor toolbar so you can add your attempt into your question.

Comment: Since D8, begins with a D I would say it is a type of diode.

Comment: How ironic that they did a poor soldering job on the soldering iron PCB.

Comment: Can we get this guy some upvotes for actually doing the work and coming back with a decent schematic pls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not going to trace it out, but it doesn't really look like a temperature controller at all. Looks more like a phase control that's only slightly more sophisticated than a light dimmer (reduced snap-on).

The diode may be a 32V diac similar to DB3, in which case the TO-92 part U10 would be something like a MAC97.

Edit:

Based on your schematic- this is a simple phase control. The pot adjusts the trigger angle. The trimpot is used to trim the minimum power setting. The bridge and R25/26 are used to help reset the timing capacitor C1 to reduce "snap on"
effect. The time constant is between the pot/trimpot,R and C1.

When the voltage across C1 exceeds about 32V it triggers on, triggering the triac. Image from [here](https://electricalacademia.com/electronics/scr-thyristor-phase-control-circuit/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Spehro, yes its a temprature controller and U10 is MAC97A6. I am not sure about the functionality of diode D8 (blue) which you suggested as diac. Can you please explain it a little.

Comment: @IffiHus I doubt it's a temperature controller because there's not enough wires for that. The blue/red is connected together and clearly marked Neutral. The black/other red pair looks like the supply/switched output and the green ones are just earth. So where's the temperature sensor? Likely just phase control as said.

Comment: It's a power controller, not a temperature controller (there's no sensor). You can look up the functionality of a diac. [Here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/db3.pdf) is a datasheet. It  simply breaks down and latches when the voltage (in either direction) across it exceeds some threshold. That triggers the MAC triac, once every half-cycle of the mains.

Comment: Thanks Spehro, there is no temperature sensor. P1 is AC L, P6 is AC N. P4 and P5 are heater leads. Actually I just draw the circuit of the PCB but I don't know how to attach it here. Can you please guide me how to attach it here or share your email so that I can send the hand drawn schematic to you? It would be a great favour.

Comment: Upload it to an image site such as imgur.com, and put a link in your question if it doesn't allow you to directly insert an image.

Comment: Dear Spehro, I have just added the hand drawn circuit on the top with other images. Please have a look. I hope it will be clear. Being a noob I am unable to understand the functionality of the components. Kindly guide.

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind update. I am just worried that what to use for D8. It seems to be a DIAC and C32 is written on it. You also suggested to use DB3 for D8. Will DB3 be working fine with mentioned circuit and MAC97A6? Thanks!

Comment: I actually gave you a part number and linked a datasheet.

Comment: Thank you! I will use DB3with MAC9716. I hope it will work best.
Lastly, there are small resistors which I think 0.25 watt ceramic resistor (so common) and I will read the values by comparing it to color table. But I dont know about the two big resistor (R25, R26) and another one big near LED.
Can you please let me know which type of resistors they are? Which resistor I choose for those?
Diodes are also an ambiguity for me.
I wish if you could help me selecting the right big resistors and diodes.
I will be much thankful of your time.

Comment: 51K 5%maybe 2W (compare size) metal oxide film. Diodes 1N4007 etc.

Comment: Thanks. great I got all the components except fuse. Can you please let me know what rating I use;
1. If I want it to run on 110VAC?
2. If I want it to run on 220VAC?
Thanks for all you have done for me.